# Repeatedly querying xml using python

Tags: python, xml, caching, elementtree

I have some xml documents I need to run queries on. I've created some python scripts (using ElementTree) to do this, since I'm vaguely familiar with using it.

The way it works is I run the scripts several times with different arguments, depending on what I want to find out.

These files can be relatively large (10MB+) and so it takes rather a long time to parse them. On my system, just running:

```
tree = ElementTree.parse(document)
```

takes around 30 seconds, with a subsequent findall query only adding around a second to that.

Seeing as the way I'm doing this requires me to repeatedly parse the file, I was wondering if there was some sort of caching mechanism I can use so that the ElementTree.parse computation can be reduced on subsequent queries.

I realise the smart thing to do here may be to try and batch as many queries as possible together in the python script, but I was hoping there might be another way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I second the suggestion to use lxml, you can get a huge performance boost by using the builtin cElementTree.

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree
```

Comment: Yes I think that will work! The first time a query is run it takes around 15 seconds, but subsequent queries are around 1-2 seconds.

As for using lxml my reason for not doing so is that I want to make sure these scripts will work out of the box on any mac I run them on, without needing to install anything else. I don't know if there's a way I could build lxml and just bundle it together with my .py files, if so please let me know how I do this

Answer (score 1):

First off, consider using the `lxml` implementation of `ElementTree`:
http://lxml.de/
This is a wrapper for libxml2, which I find performs well.

Run python interactively, make multiple queries against the same etree object. `ipython` is an enhanced interactive python interpreter with easy access to introspection and convenience-syntax.

E.g. interactively examining [note.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml) with ipython using `lxml.etree`.

```
$ ipython
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jul 10 2008, 17:24:48)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.8.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: doc = etree.parse(open("note.xml"))

In [3]: etree.dump(doc.getroot())
<note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
In [4]: doc.xpath('/note/*')
Out[4]:
[<Element to at 89cf02c>,
 <Element from at 89cf054>,
 <Element heading at 89cf07c>,
 <Element body at 89cf0a4>]
```

Comment: A great suggestion, but not sure it will work for me as I actually want to run the python scripts from an applescript. I will see if I can make it work

Answer (score 1):

Seconding the lxml recommendation, look at this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) for how to improve performance by using an iterative (SAX-like) parsing method. It can be a pain at first since it can turn really procedural and messy, but it makes things faster. As you can see from [these benchmarks](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/), lxml is most likely your best bet for performance.